# How to initialize a UI component from a layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a newbie Android. Can I do like this: I have a xml file which contains a linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutID"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageID"            
            android:contentDescription="@string/nothing"            
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"            
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
            />

    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

From any part of code, can I load it to a linearLayout like:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(R.id.linearLayoutID);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) ll.findViewById(R.id.imageID);
TextView iv = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.textID);
```

Remember the question I want to ask is from a separate layout file, we don't load into an activity or a fragment and thereby use findViewByID, we directly load the xml file to an UI component like LinearLayout, ImageView, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From any part of code, can I load it to a linearLayout like:

Not with the code that you have:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(R.id.linearLayoutID);
```

Instead, use:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.whatever_name_you_gave_it, theParentViewGroup, true);
```

where:

- `theParentViewGroup` is whatever container will hold this `LinearLayout`
- the third parameter is `true` if you want this `LinearLayout` added to the container right away, or `false` if you will add it to the container yourself (or other framework code will add it to the container, such as in `getView()` on a `ListAdapter`)